# ADO YAML pipeline: deploy nightly OR when manual approval is given

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are currently switching over from Classic (UI) Azure Pipelines to YAML pipelines.

We would like to deploy a branch every night to an environment (when changes have occurred) and also be able to deploy to this environment manually. With the Classic pipelines it was easy to setup a scheduled deploy to an environment that could also be triggered manually when desired.

In the new YAML pipelines we currently use the "Business hours"
[check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) to make sure the nightly deploy takes place, but we are unable to override the check when a manual deployment is needed.

Is there a way to setup a YAML pipeline where a deploy waits for either a manual approval or a scheduled trigger to occur?

Comment: Why do you have the Business hours check for the nightly?

Comment: > In case you want all deployments to your environment to happen in a specific time window only, then business hours check is the ideal solution.
Using it ensures the deploy is triggered at the start of the configured "business hours". I.e. it seemed a convenient way to trigger a deploy within a specific time window. Although it feels a slight bit off to refer to the night / our off hours as our business hours.

Comment: Instead of using business hour gate, you could trigger your pipeline using a cron. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?msclkid=ff583742b59711ec9f814cf385f41549&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml . This way you could also trigger your pipeline manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have been experimenting with the schedules block / cron driven approach today. But it seems designed to schedule the running of the entire pipeline, rather than a single stage. 

In an ideal world, we would have a commit trigger the build stage and then follow a successful build with a deployment to an environment after a) a manual approval is given or b) a cron is triggered.